# Меню jcarousel картинки на фоне пунктов меню не прокручиваются

Tags: javascript, jquery

Достался от предшественника код меню. При установке значений `auto:1` и `wrap: circle` по кругу прокручивается только текст, картинки на фоне пунктов меню проезжают один раз и больше не возвращается. Функцию прилагаю. Заранее благодарю за помощь

ссылка на файл с функцией: http://delosystems.ru/bitrix/templates/actualbiz/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js

Может, стоит убрать подключение фоновых картинок из этой функции и вставить их в шаблон на *php*? Буду признателен, если подскажете, как убрать картинки из этой функции.